# Pandas version 0.12 to version 0.13 to_datetime incompatibility

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, monthcalendar

I have a Pandas version 0.12 data frame. I am trying to convert the months within a string `series` to textual format, e.g. `04 = April`, `05 = May`. I ended up having to work with two different versions (12 vs 13) of Pandas, which seem to have substantial interface changes.

```
df['date']
0    15/04/2013
1    09/02/2015
2    05/01/2015
3    26/01/2015
4    26/01/2015
Name: date, dtype: object

type(df['date'][0])
<type 'str'>
```

The below code works with Pandas version 0.13, and converts, e.g. `15/02/2015` to `15 February 2015`, for each entry in the `series`.

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d/%m/%Y").apply( lambda x:  x.date().strftime('%d %B %Y') )
```

But it throws an error with version 0.12:

```
File "/.../pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 124, in to_datetime values = _convert_listlike(arg.values, box=False) File "/.../pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 103, in _convert_listlike result = tslib.array_strptime(arg, format) File "tslib.pyx", line 1112, in pandas.tslib.array_strptime (pandas/tslib.c:18277) 
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I just need to get this done with, any ideas on what the Pandas 12 vesion of the above code would be? I do not have to use `to_datetime()` either, so any alternative solution suggestions are very welcome!

**EDIT:**

I tried this line upon @EdChum's recommendation:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y')).apply( lambda x: x.date().strftime('%d %B %Y') )
```

But it gives the error:

```
File "/.../pandas/core/series.py", line 2536, in apply mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype) File "inference.pyx", line 864, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:42840) File " in <lambda> df['date'] = df['date'].apply( lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y')).apply( lambda x: x.date().strftime('%d %B %Y') ) TypeError: must be string, not float
```

I think this answers @joris's comment as well, it seems the issue is with the `.apply()` part. I do not understand how/where a `float` is created in this line of code...

Comment: Can you try this and if it works I'll post as answer: `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y')).apply( lambda x:  x.date().strftime('%d %B %Y') )`

Comment: This works for me in pandas 0.12. Can you check which part throws the error? (the `to_datetime` part, or the `apply` part)

Comment: @joris, from the exception (added in the question), I believe it is in `to_datetime`

Comment: I'll just note that instead of `.apply(lambda x:  x.date().strftime('%d %B %Y'))` - you can avoid the lambda and `.date()` over head, and use `.apply('%d %B %Y'.format)` instead...

Comment: @EdChum, it works for version 0.13, checking for 12 now.

Comment: Yup @JonClements is correct this is much cleaner: `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d %B %Y'))`

Comment: @EdChum, Unfortunately it failed in version 0.12. I am extending the question to include the new error.

Comment: @Zhubarb move out your lambda into a function instead, then pass that... Then see if an exception gets thrown from there... that should clear any potential namespacing issues and make debugging easier

Comment: Is it possible that not all values in your `'date'` column are strings? I think it contains some missing values (NaN or None). The `to_datetime` function in 0.12 could not yet handle this, and in 0.13 this was an improvement). Can you try your original code on `df['date'].dropna()`? This also explaing the error message you get with the suggestions.

Comment: @joris, thank you - this may actually be the issue, i will dig further.

Comment: You can test if you have duff values by putting your code in a function that catches the exception: `def func(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
    except TypeError:
        return pd.NaT
df['date'].apply(func)` but calling `dropna` and comparing the lengths will tell you also if you have `NaN` values

Comment: @EdChum for more recent versions, the `coerce=True` keywords is there for this case (so no need for such manual catching and applying), although this does not yet seem to work for pandas 0.12

Comment: @joris, the issue was as you describe - due to NaN's. I am happy to accept your comment if you want to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is due to some missing values. If you use `dropna` before using `to_datetime` and `apply(... strftime())`, this will work. A small example:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
         date
0  15/04/2013
1  09/02/2015
2         NaN

In [21]: df['date2'] = df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dropna(), format="%d/
%m/%Y").apply( lambda x:  x.date().strftime('%d %B %Y') )

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
               date             date2
0     15 April 2013     15 April 2013
1  09 February 2015  09 February 2015
2               NaN               NaN
```

The reason for the difference between pandas 0.12 and 0.13 is that in 0.12 `to_datetime` could not yet handle this, and starting from 0.13 it does.